# Sending MMS over HTTP using GPRS modem

Tags: c#, .net, modem, mms, at-command

I am to develop application to send Email (with attachment) and MMS using Telit GL865 modem. Modem does not support WAP communication. Can MMS be sent using HTTP via GPRS? Is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

In general it's possible but its really hard to find some info on the net.

To send an MMS using HTTP protocol you need to use HTTP POST method.

In the header put MMS proxy addr, port, MMS Central addr etc (all provided  by the carrier). While as the data for the POST method simply provide formatted MMS.

Make sure you are connected to the MMS APN before sending an POST message to the server.

Comment: If possible post a dummy example to provide more clarity about what you've said...